# Required version of TLS for communication with EventHub

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

We are currently using EventHubProducerClient from Azure.Messaging.EventHubs 5.1.0.0.
Does it support tls 1.2 for communication with EventHub ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/messaging-on-azure/enforcing-tls-1-2-use-with-azure-service-bus/ba-p/370912) article:

> If your Service Bus clients are up to date, you are generally using TLS 1.2.

As Event Hub is built on top of Service Bus, the same applies - plus the article is already somewhat old.

Comment: Found in source code of Azure client : 
    public TlsTransportSettings(TransportSettings innerSettings, bool isInitiator)
    {
      this.innerSettings = innerSettings;
      this.IsInitiator = isInitiator;
      this.Protocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
      this.CheckCertificateRevocation = true;
    }

Comment: yeah you can force your client to use TLS 1.2 only - but any modern OS will do that anyway

Comment: Both service and 5.1.0 client support TLS 1.2. It should do 1.2 unless you force downgrade during TLS negotiation.